# Woher stammt das »großes Indianer-Ehrenwort«?

Tags: etymology, expression

Als ich einmal wieder meine Lieblingskinderserie, den *kleinen Vampir* geschaut habe, ist mir folgender Dialog in die Ohren gesprungen:

> Ich möchte das Wort »Vampir« die nächsten Wochen nicht mehr hören!
>
> Großes Indianer-Ehrenwort!

Die Bedeutung und Verwendung ist mir klar: Wer ausdrücken möchte, dass es sich nicht nur um ein Versprechen handelt, sondern dass es ein richtig ernsthaftes Versprechen ist, das man auf jeden Fall einzuhalten gedenkt, kann es als »großes Indianer-Ehrenwort« titulieren. Ich würde es der (Grundschul-) Kindersprache zuordnen. Der *kleine Vampir* hat mit Indianern ungefähr so viel zu tun wie mit Astronauten, was vermuten lässt, dass der Ausdruck im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch verstanden wird.

Lässt sich das große Indianer-Ehrenwort auf eine Quelle zurückverfolgen? Oder ist es langsam aufgetaucht und speist sich aus einer Vielzahl verschiedener Einflüsse?

Comment: @PerlDuck Ich habe alle Romane von Karl May gelesen, und dort kommt es nicht vor.

Answer (score 8):

Dass das *Indianerehrenwort*, zumindest im von Google erfassten deutschsprachigen Schrifttum, erst in jüngerer Zeit auftaucht, hat Hubert [in seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32173/9091) belegt, auch wenn ich seiner Karl-May-These nicht zustimmen mag. Mark Twain's "Huckleberry Finn" kommt als direkter Ursprung auch nicht in Frage. Wie wir beim [Projekt Gutenberg](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/huckleberry-finns-abenteuer-und-fahrten-1670/25) sehen, wurde [*Honest injun*](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32172/9091) ursprünglich mit "Hand auf's Herz" übersetzt.

Der Ausdruck weist aber starke Ähnlichkeit auf zu *Pfadfinderehrenwort* und [*Pionierehrenwort*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pionierorganisation_Ernst_Th%C3%A4lmann#Pionierehrenwort), für die Google Books Belege von [1963](https://books.google.de/books?id=PAsVAAAAIAAJ&q=pfadfinderehrenwort&dq=pfadfinderehrenwort&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y) bzw. [1962](https://www.google.de/search?q=pionierehrenwort&hl=de&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A31.12.1970&tbm=bks) liefert. Auch wenn der Beleg für *Pionierehrenwort* ein Jahr älter ist, glaube ich, dass eher die Pfadfinder hier das Original darstellen - die sozialistischen Pionierorganisationen haben sie sich ja anscheinend ein Stück weit zum Vorbild genommen (anderes Thema...). Laut Wikipedia geht das [Pfadfinderversprechen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfadfinderversprechen) auf das Jahr 1908 zurück. Das Gelöbnis der Pioniere sieht nach dem Pendant dazu aus.

Pfadfinder und (zumindest vom Anspruch her) die sozialistischen Pioniere gehör(t)en zur Jugendkultur und stellen Gruppen dar, in denen Ehre und Ehrlichkeit einen hohen Stellenwert einnehmen. Gleiches gilt für die Indianer - auch dank, aber nicht erst seit Karl May (man denke nur an [Cooper](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Fenimore_Cooper)). Mit der abnehmenden Popularität der beiden erstgenannten dürfte, so meine Hypothese, der Anreiz gestiegen sein, den ursprünglichen begriff auf ein zeitloseres, aber ebenfalls passendes Sujet zu übertragen.

Comment: Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Abenteuer_des_Huckleberry_Finn) wurde die erste deutsche Übersetzung von Huck Finn im Jahre 1890 veröffentlicht; der Gutenberg-Text entstammt einer Veröffentlichung von 1962 – auch wenn der Autor der gleiche ist. Weitreichende Edierungen zwischen verschiedenen Auflagen sind nicht ausgeschlossen. (Dennoch +1.)

Comment: Diese These kann auch die leise Ironie, die dem *Indianerehrenwort* innewohnt, erklären.

Answer (score 7):

According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Honest%20injun):

Großes Indianerehrenwort! = Honest injun! [Am.] [coll.] [now considered offensive]

Possibly, the expression *Honest injun!* [first appeared](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/honest-injun) in Mark Twain's 1884 novel "[Adventures of Huckleberry Finn](https://americanliterature.com/author/mark-twain/book/the-adventures-of-huckleberry-finn/chapter-33)". At the beginning of Chapter 33, there is the following dialogue between Huckleberry Finn and Tom Sawyer (Huckleberry thinks Tom has come back from the dead): "I (Sawyer) says: "I hain't come back- I hain't been gone." When he heard my voice, it righted him up some, but he warn't quite satisfied yet. He says: "Don't you play nothing on me, because I wouldn't on you. **Honest injun**, now, you ain't a ghost?" "**Honest injun**, I ain't," I says."

And about the origin of the phrase, the following is to be read in this [Yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081027192701AAhxrKm) answer:

> Originally, in the early 1800s, it was believed that Native Indians
>   (Injuns) were intrinsically more honest than were the White Men who
>   stole their land and misled Native Americans. But Indians, being more
>   child-like, honest, and moral were seldom the dishonest ones.
>   **Therefore when a white man made a vow they would raise their hand and
>   proclaim, "Honest Injun" meaning, I'm speaking like an Indian
>   (trustworthy) rather than as a white man (dishonest).**

Comment: "now considered offensive" - interessanter Hinweis, der so meines Erachtens auf den deutschen Begriff nicht zutrifft (auch wenn dieser, wie oben bemerkt, definitiv der Kindersprache zuzuordnen ist).

Comment: "it was believed that Native Indians (Injuns) were intrinsically more honest (...) **But** Indians, being more (...) honest, (...) were seldom the dishonest ones." - ich verstehe ehrlich gesagt nicht, was uns das von mir hervorgehobene "but" sagen soll. Ich vermag in den Aussagen keinen Widerspruch zu erkennen.

Comment: Yes, that "But" looks out of place (To me, the sentence reads better without it altogether). But, that's what the original answer stated. Since that "But" did not change the overall meaning of the author's point, I preserved the original wording.

Comment: If this ends up being the best-sourced answer, I would have to mark that expression as the one Indian mention in German that does not derive back to Karl May. Interesting!

Comment: Für mich sieht es so aus, als sei die Frage weiterhin offen.
Bei Karl May kommt die Redewendung nicht vor, jedenfalls nicht
in den Romanen, die im Projekt Gutenberg enthalten sind,
und sie paßt auch stilistisch nicht zu May.
Bei Mark Twain kommt "Honest injun!" vor,
aber das "Große Indianerehrenwort!" findet sich nur in einer
*späten* Übersetzung, nicht in der *frühen* im Projekt Gutenberg,
was eher darauf hindeutet, daß der Übersetzer die Formulierung
nicht erfunden hat, sondern eine zu seiner Zeit schon
gebräuchliche Wendung benutzt hat.

Comment: Schaut man bei *ngrams*, findet man die ersten Vorkommen des Begriffes "Indianerehrenwort" erst um 1990!

Comment: This is a very interesting contribution about a similar phrase in English - but I do not see any links in the answer to the German word in question.

Comment: @Matthias Check the very first link, which links the English to the German phrase ;)

Comment: dict.cc only tells, that "honest injun" is a translation of "Großes Indianerehrenwort" But that does not necessarily (nor even probably, I'd say) means that both notions share the same etymology, or that one stems from the other. That's why I gave -1 here.

Comment: I would have preferred a summary instead of a textual copy. The link seems broken, so I can't confirm.

Answer (score 3):

*Leider kann ich die genaue Quelle ebensowenig dingfest machen, wie alle anderen bisher Antwortenden. Normalerweise würde ich daher hier nicht antworten. Da aber so viele falsche Spekulationen herumgeistern, schreibe ich eine Antwort, die zumindest den ideengeschichtlichen Hintergrund etwas erläutert, dem der Begriff wahrscheinlich entspringt.*

Der Ausdruck hängt mit dem (europäischen) romantisierenden Bild von Indianern zusammen, denen besondere Tugenden, wie etwa Tapferkeit und auch Ehrlichkeit zugeschrieben wurden. Dieses romantisierende Bild wird in der Vorstellung vom 'Edlen Wilden' (vgl. [de:wikipedia:Edler Wilder](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edler_Wilder); besser: [en:wikipedia:Noble savage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_savage)) zusammengefasst. Die Vorstellung vom Edlen Wilden kam mit der Entdeckung Amerikas auf und hatte auch in Aufklärung und Romantik Konjunktur. Sie hängt eng mit dem naturrechtlichen und kulturkritischen Vorstellungen zusammen, die die zeitgenössische, als negativ bewertete, Gesellschaft kritisieren, indem sie in die Vergangenheit einen idealisierten Naturzustand projizieren, und die Kultur mit Konzepten von 'Verfall' verantwortlich für den vermeintlichen oder tatsächlichen moralischen Niedergang der angeborenen guten Eigenschaften des Menschen machen. Für die vielen zahlreichen literarischen Beispiele für dieses Konzept seit dem 16. Jahrhundert siehe den oben verlinkten englischen Wikipedia-Artikel.

Die Indianerromane von James F. Cooper, Karl May, oder auch Liselotte Welskopf-Henrich machen ausgiebig Gebrauch von diesem Klischee. Karl May hat sicher maßgeblich zur Konjunktur des Konzepts im deutschsprachigen Raum beigetragen; er ist aber mitnichten der Urheber der Idee. Karl Mays Indianerromane sind im Gegenteil eine verhältnismäßig spätes Auftreten des Bildes vom Edlen Wilden. Als direkte Quelle Karl der Redewendung kann Karl May ausgeschlossen werden - in keinem seiner Romane kommt die Wendung vor.

Answer (score 2):

Dem letzen Beitrag kann ich nur zustimmen. Mir ist diese Redewendung seit langem vor 1982 bekannt.
 Als Kind spielte ich gern Cowboy und Indianer. Manchmal, selten genug leider, hatte auch mein Vater für mich Zeit. Wärend eines Ausfluges mit meinen Eltern ins grüne, nahm mir mein Vater im Spiel, das "große Indianer Ehrenwort" ab. Ich erinnere mich daran als wäre es gestern. Tatsächlich muss es so um 1966/67 geschehen sein. Den Zeitpunkt kann ich so genau bestimmen, da meine Geschwister zu dieser Zeit noch nicht geboren waren. Mein Geburtsjahr ist 1961.
Nicht nur in meiner Familie auch seitens der Großeltern, war das 'große Indianer Ehrenwort' das Pondon zu 'Hand aufs Herz',sondern auch durchaus geläufig im Freundeskreis. Hier nicht nur im Spiel, sondern auch als absolute Versicherung es wirklich ehrlich zu meinen. Und es besass einen deutlich höheren Stellenwert und mehr Gewicht als das heutige infllationär übliche: "Isch schwör".

Comment: Pondon kenn ich nicht. Meinst Du [Pendant](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Pendant)?

Comment: Was ist der »letzte Beitrag«? Beiträge werden hier nach Wertung sortiert; Beiträge mit gleicher Wertung werden zufällig angeordnet. Bitte füge einen Link zu dem entsprechenden Beitrag ein oder nenne seinen Autor, damit ich ihn zuordnen kann.

Comment: *deutlich höheren Stellenwert und mehr Gewicht als das heutige infllationär übliche: "Isch schwör".* Fantastischer Einwurf, völlig unsachgemäß, aber durchaus significant wenn man wie ich pflegt auf indigenen Ursprung zu untersuchen, denn *indigen*, *ingenious* usw. stehen im Vergleich nach meinem Dafürhalten nicht hinter *Answer* bzw. *Antwort* zurück, d.h. eben nicht *anti*, *wider-* oder *Gegenwort*, sondern wohl eher *Eingeschworen, Eingabe* wie *einstweilig*, *einstig*, vgl. *ancien*, sprich Erbwort. Huzza! Ausarbeitung der These bleibt dem Leser überlassen.

Comment: Ich kenne das Indianerehrenwort wie auch den kleinen Vampir aus meiner Kindheit in den 80ern.

Answer (score 0):

Der deutsche Schriftsteller Karl May hat Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts unter anderem Bücher über das Leben der amerikanischen Indianer geschrieben, ohne selbst in Amerika gewesen zu sein. Er reiste zwar einmal (1908) nach New York, allerdings sind seine Bücher »Winnetou« (Bände I bis III), »Old Surehand« (alle 3 Bände), »Der Schatz im Silbersee«, »Der schwarze Mustang« usw. viele Jahre davor erschienen. Lediglich »Winnetou IV« hat er nach seiner Amerikareise geschrieben.

In diesen Büchern hat Karl May den Indianern eine größtenteils frei erfundene Kultur angedichtet, die von einer pathetischen Vorstellung von Ehre geprägt war. Diesem Ehr-Begriff entspringt das in Mays Büchern häufig erwähnte Vertrauen darauf, dass ein Indianer ein Versprechen, dass er einmal im Rahmen einer bestimmten kurzen Zeremonie gegeben hat, unter keinen Umständen brechen würde. Dieses heilige Versprechen ist das Indianerehrenwort.

Dadurch, dass die Karl May-Bücher vor allem Anfang bis Mitte des 20. Jahrhunderts sehr verbreitet waren, und später durch diverse Verfilmungen einem noch breiteren Publikum im deutschen Sprachraum bekannt gemacht wurden, ging der Begriff »Indianerehrenwort« in den deutschen Wortschatz ein.

Der Begrifft bedeutet: »Ein Versprechen, bei dem man vor hat, es auf keinen Fall zu brechen.«

Dieser Begriff hat keinen echten Ursprung in der Kultur der amerikanischen Urbevölkerung. Das soll aber nicht bedeuten, dass Ehre und der Wille Versprechen einzuhalten, kein Teil dieser Kultur wären. Aber der Ursprung des Begriffs sind die Bücher Karl Mays, die mit der realen uramerikanischen Kultur relativ wenig zu tun haben.

Nachtrag, um einem Missverständnis vorzubeugen:
Ich glaube nicht, das Karl May selbst den Begriff »Indianerehrenwort« verwendet hat. Wer das Wort letztendlich erfunden hat, weiß ich nicht. Aber das Wort geht geht auf Mays Indianer-Darstellung zurück und wurde von Karl May-Konsumenten in Anlehnung an Mays Indianer-Bild verwendet.

### Nachtrag 2:

Dieses [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Indianerehrenwort&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIndianerehrenwort%3B%2Cc0) belegt recht eindrucksvoll, dass das deutsche Wort »Indianerehrenwort« weder Mark Twain, noch Karl May bekannt gewesen sein dürfte:

[image: ngram Indianerehrenwort]

Die älteste Quelle, die ich finden konnte stammt aus dem Jahr 1982. Es ist das Buch »[Entzug, oder, Die Angst vor der Angst von Doris J. Joachim](https://books.google.at/books?id=9mnfAAAAMAAJ&q=Indianerehrenwort&dq=Indianerehrenwort&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y)« Aber Frau Joachim verwendet das Wort in einem wörtlichen Zitat, dessen wahren Urheber ich nicht ausfindig machen konnte. Aber wer auch immer das war: Auch die in dem Buch zitierte Person wird das Wort höchstwahrscheinlich nicht selbst erfunden haben.

Vielmehr ist anzunehmen, dass das Wort »Indianerehrenwort« 1982 bereits Teil des allgemeinen deutschen Wortschatzes war. Sehr viel früher kann das Wort aber noch nicht in Gebrauch gewesen sein, weil es sonst wohl im ngramm deutlichere Spuren hinterlassen hätte.

### Fakten:

- Der Gebrauch des Wortes »Indianerehrenwort« lässt sich erst ab 1982 belegen und findet sich in einer Publikation, die nichts mit Indianern oder Ehre zu tun hat (sondern mit Drogensucht).
- Der Amerikaner Mark Twain kommt als Urheber des deutschen Wortes »Indianerehrenwort« kaum in Betracht, weil er, obwohl er die deutsche Sprache beherrschte, selbst kaum etwas in deutscher Sprache publiziert hat. Darüberhinaus starb er 1910, also 72 Jahre vor der ersten belegbaren Erwähnung des nachgefragten Wortes.
- Der 1912 verstorbene Karl May war selbst auch nicht der Urheber dieses Wortes.
- Das Mitte des 20. Jahrhunderts im deutschen Sprachraum vorherrschende Bild der Indianerkultur wurde maßgeblich von den Büchern Karl Mays geprägt. Die Verfilmungen dieser Bücher verstärkten dieses Bild noch weiter.

Insgesamt lassen diese Fakten den Schluss zu, dass das Wort »Indianerehrenwort« in Anlehnung an das Karl May’sche Indianerbild in der deutschsprachigen Bevölkerung entstanden ist. Vor allem als kulturelles Erbe der Karl May-Verfilmungen, der 1960er und 1970er Jahre.

Comment: Hast Du irgendeinen konkreten Beleg für *die stehende Wendung*
"(großes) Indianer-Ehrenwort" in einem Roman von Karl May?
Es ist zwar vierzig Jahre her, daß ich die Bücher gelesen habe,
aber für mich klingt diese Redewendung sehr unmayisch.
In der Übersetzung von Tom Sawyer (siehe Eugenes Antwort)
kommt es in der Tat vor
("Ben, ich würd's ja gern tun, großes Indianerehrenwort;
aber Tante Polly - weißt du, Jim wollte, und sie hat ihn nicht gelassen.")

Comment: @Uwe: Ich habe nirgendwo behauptet, Karl May hätte diese Wendung selbst verwendet. Ich habe behauptet, dass sie auf seine Darstellung der Indianer zurückgeht. Und in der Tom Sayer-Übersetzung finde ich das Wort auch nur in einer Übersetzung aus dem Jahr 2007. Das Wort »Indianerehrenwort« kenne ich aber bereits aus meiner Kindheit (geboren 1965)

Comment: Es war aber gerade die Frage, wo die Wendung herkommt.
Die Bedeutung war schon klar.

Comment: @Uwe: Findest du, ich hätte die Frage nicht beantwortet? Meine Antwort kann verkürzt werden zu: »Die Wendung wurde von Karl-May-Lesern ins Leben gerufen«. Ich finde, das ist eine vollkommen erschöpfende Antwort auf die Frage »Wo kommt die Wendung her?«

Comment: Mark Twain hat Karl May gelesen? Gibt es dafür Belege?

Comment: @userunknown: Wie kommst du denn auf diesen Schmarrn? Mark Twain hat sein Buch auf Englisch geschrieben. 2007 erschien dann eine deutsche Übersetzung, in der das Wort »Indianerehrenwort« vorkommt.

Comment: @Takkat: Beachte das nun eingebettete ngram. Ich bleibe bei meiner Behauptung, dass weder Mark Twain noch Karl May das Wort verwendet haben, sondern dass es erst später entstanden ist. Es ist sozusagen auf Karl Mays Mist gewachsen.

Comment: @userunknown: Beachte das nun eingebettete ngram. Ich bleibe bei meiner Behauptung, dass weder Mark Twain noch Karl May das Wort verwendet haben, sondern dass es erst später entstanden ist. Es ist sozusagen auf Karl Mays Mist gewachsen.

Comment: @uwe: Beachte das nun eingebettete ngram. Ich bleibe bei meiner Behauptung, dass weder Mark Twain noch Karl May das Wort verwendet haben, sondern dass es erst später entstanden ist. Es ist sozusagen auf Karl Mays Mist gewachsen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: so gefällt mir die Antwort viel besser. :)

Comment: +1 für die Recherche zu ngrams. Aber der "Mist", auf dem das Wort gewachsen ist, ist nur zum Teil Karl May zuzurechnen, und er hat die Indianerromantik auch nicht begründet.

Comment: +1 für die Zusätze, aber es könnte am Anfang darauf hingewiesen werden, dass die ersten Absätze doch nicht den Tatsachen entsprechen.

Comment: Dein Diagramm widerlegt Absatz 3. Bücher und Filme (60er-Jahre) waren längst verbreitet aber das Wort tauchte nicht auf. So sehr ich verstehe, dass Du einen Essay zum Thema *K. May und die fiktive Indianerkultur* schreiben willst, das war nicht gefragt und ohne Untersuchung der Quelle bleibt der Einfluss Mays Spekulation.

Comment: Auf den Schmarrn komme ich durch Uwes Zitat. Wenn es eine 1:1 Übersetzung ist, dann hätte Twain das Wort geprägt und müsste, wenn es auf May zurückgeht, May gelesen haben.

Comment: Der Begriff des "Edlen Wilden" ist wesentlich älter und wurde nicht von Karl May erfunden, sondern allerhöchstens aufgegriffen. Die Bücher von James Fenimore Cooper sind wesentlich älter und verwenden dasselbe Bild für die amerikanischen Ureinwohner. Nachdem wir geklärt haben, das Karl May den Begriff nicht verwendet hat, sollten wir nun auch noch klären, dass er auf seine Darstellung der Indianer auch nicht beweisbar zurückgeht.

Comment: -1 für "Aber der Ursprung des Begriffs sind die Bücher Karl Mays, die mit der realen uramerikanischen Kultur relativ wenig zu tun haben." Das ist einfach falsch. Karl May ist ein sehr später Rezipient der Theorie vom Edlen Wilden, keineswegs der Urheber des Konzepts.

Comment: Den kleinen Vampir aus der Frage gibt's seit Ende der 1970er. Je nachdem, wo genau dort das Indianerehrenwort vorkommt, ist es ggf. ein früherer Beleg als das Buch von 1982.

Answer (score 0):

Nach der Datenlage vermute ich als Übertragung in der deutschsprachigen Fassung einer sozialistischen Fernsehserie/-sendung aus dem Ostblock für Kinder vor 1979, also, dass man entsprechendes Vokabular aus dem Realsozialismus in die westdeutsche Lebenswirklichkeit übertragen wollte.

Schon in den 80er Jahren wird es in Schriften in einer Art und Weise verwendet, die auf eine Verwendung im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch schliessen lassen, also dass erwachsenen Lesern die Redewendung zum Indianerspiel von Kinder (und darum geht es, nicht Indianer) bekannt sein muss.

Comment: Interessant! Was ist denn die Datenlage? Auf welche Daten beziehst du dich, und wie können Außenstehende das nachvollziehen? Herzlich willkommen auf german.SE! Schön, dass du gleich mit einer Antwort einsteigst!

Comment: Welche sozialistische Fernsehserie/-sendung? Bitte mit mehr Informationen und Quellen unterfüttern.